# Web API how to have one route with multiple actions

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Using MVC's WebAPI, I have 1 url that I'd like to use for both GET and POST.

Example:

```
GET /person?personId=5
POST /person - the post would contain info about the new person to post, like { firstName: "Bob" }
```

My route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "Person-GetAndPost",
  routeTemplate: "person",
  defaults: new { controller = "Person", action = "Get|Post" }
);
```

When visiting `person?personId=5` in my browser, I get the error `No action was found on the controller 'Device' that matches the name 'Get|Post'.`

Here are the actions in my controller:

```
// with the action name called "Get", MVC Web API should match the verb GET with this action
public MyModels.Person Get(int personId)
{
    return; // return the person
}

// with the action name called "Post", MVC Web API should match the verb POST with this action
public MyModels.Person Post(MyModels.Person person)
{
    return; // return the updated person
}
```

Is this even possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont set the action :

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "Person-GetAndPost",
  routeTemplate: "person",
  defaults: new { controller = "Person" }
);
```

Comment: that worked! altho, I had to make sure that controller only had 1 GET action in it, otherwise, MVC Web API does not know which one to use. good to know.